# .NET Blazor Build error

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

I have tried to run the out of the box Blazor application to try out C# WebAssembly.  I am running into issues when trying to run it different ways.  I have also tried to hack the `runtimeconfig.json` according to this https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/7543

**Running IIS Express**

[image]

**Running BlazorApplication1**
The program '[42032] dotnet.exe' has exited with code -2147450749 (0x80008083).

**Running in command line**
It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The specified framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '2.0.0-preview3-25512-01' was not found.
  - Check application dependencies and target a framework version installed at:
      \
  - Alternatively, install the framework version '2.0.0-preview3-25512-01'.

Comment: Have you installed .net core SDK?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the 2.1 preview of the .net core framework installed for Blazor to work: [download here](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/dotnet-core/sdk-2.1.300-preview1)